# How to highlight text in qpdfview?

Tags: 14.04, pdf

I've downloaded qpdfview for highlight some text in a pdf. But I can't see the highlight option. How to highlight text in qpdfview?

Comment: Does the Edit menu have an "Add Annotation" entry?

Comment: @muru, Yes, it has. And here is the highlight option. At least I found it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Edit/Add annotation` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Select the text area (that will be highlighted) and `Add_highlight` to highlight text.

Answer (score 5):

At least on the newer version of qpdfviewer (0.4.14), holding down `Shift` lets you select text, column-wise.